# Change 'My documents link' to a Drive

Tags: authentication, batch-file

I'm trying to find a BAT code that changes the 'my documents' link from
'C:\Documents and Settings\%Username%\My Documents\'
To
'H:\'
This would allow my users to be able to click 'My Documents' and it would take them to their H:

Could anyone help me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use a local policy and set a roaming profile works for the accounts you put in.?

Comment: I mean on the desktop. I have edited the profile settings to set the users document area, But when they login, on the desktop it says the original link. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specify `/D` to change the drive also.

```
CD /D %root%
```

[Batch Files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php)

Comment: Perhaps you want to mean /D? `CD /D %root%`

Comment: @Aacini am sorry about this. I have updated solution now